# How do I auto-complete an email form field when someone clicks a link in an email?

Tags: forms, url-parameters

I have a form that has basic fields: name, address, email, etc. Someone gets to this form by clicking a link in an email send to him/her. How do I build the link in a way that when the person clicks it and lands on the form page, the email field is automatically completed with his/her email address? Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass his emailid in query string and check in form if its there then put it in the text box.

Am assuming you landing to your page from your another page.